# HTML Helper not recognizing "@Html.InlineImage"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, email, razor, html-helper, mvcmailer

I am trying to embed an email image in MVCMailer.  The Github MvcMailer Step by Step Guide does provide a solution as shown below:

STEP BY STEP GUIDE:

```
//Place this in the View:
@Html.InlineImage("logo", "Company Logo")

//Place this in the mailer:
var resources = new Dictionary<string, string>();
resources["logo"] = logoPath;
PopulateBody(mailMessage, "WelcomeMessage", resources);
```

My problem is, the view does not recognize the `@Html.InlineImage`. It recognizes other html helpers, just not "InlineImage". In fact, it never comes in *intellisense* when I type `@Html`.

I think that this is not supported in MVC 4.  Can anyone point me in the right direction and tell me what I need to do to get this working?

Comment: FYI, Here is the error message I'm getting: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'InlineImage' and no extension method 'InlineImage' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Make sure you have true configurations for that view scope. Check the local **web.config** file contents. And we suppose you have included related assembly references to your project.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's too late, but I solved it adding "@using Mvc.Mailer;" at the top of the email View.

Answer (score 0):

I did not figure out the @Html.InlineImage issue, but I did find a work around.  Simply using:
`<img style="width: 243px; height: 91px" src="cid:logo" alt="Logo"/>` in my view took care of the problem.  Thank you all for looking to help.